# iOS - fit buttons in a row

Tags: ios, button, screen

I am creating an iOS application using Storyboard.

In the bottom of my view I want to have 6-7  buttons one after the other horizontally that take all the screen width. How can I make them auto-resize their width so that they take all the screen width in iphone 5 and iphone 6 screens?

In the respective Android app I am using a gridview with X columns so it manages to give the correct width.

Comment: Can you use Auto Layout?

Comment: @Raam Yes I can use auto-layout. How do I tell to resize all buttons equally to take all the available space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add auto layout constraints in storyboard:

1. Select first button (left most): add top, left, right & height constraints.
2. Select other 6 buttons: add top, right & height constraints
3. Select all buttons: add equal widths constraint.

Comment: This is almost what I did yesterday and it worked! Solution will be accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Autoresizing in Size Inspector,
 here i have attach the image for your understanding.

[image]

Comment: No no no. Please start using auto layout!